# TFS new PC Checkout

Tags: c#, version-control, tfs

i have a project in TFS. I have PC A and it has the project checked in. I bought a new PC setup my workspace under the advanced menu and connected to my TFS server. How do i download the project. I cant find any tutorial on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After connecting to TFS server go to Source Control Explorer, then Right click on the project that you want to download and Click on `Get Latest Version`. That will ask to map to your local filesystem.

Let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: when you say source control explorer do you mean "Team explorer"

Comment: No. They are different. Team Explorer is used to manage specific team projects (builds, work items, reports, etc). Source Control Explorer allows you to browse files under source control.

Comment: Got it thanks - From the menu bar choose View, Other Windows, Source Control Explorer.

Comment: Under VS2012 source control explorer is accessible from Team Explorer

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to the TFS server & define a workspace mapping. Once you do that, you need to connect to a specific team project (or projects) and `Get Latest`. This will download the source files from the server to your local machine. Then you can check in/out as normal

Comment: where is the check out button ? under what screen or ?

Comment: Right click on a file in Source Control Explorer. The context menu will give you the option to "Check Out For Edit..." and "Check In Pending Changes".